# Changing the Updatable property of a View Object Attribute through code

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Is there a way to set the "Updatable" property of an attribute in a view object through code ?

I checked the API docs for the AttributeDef class but there is no method to set this. there is a constant (UPDATEABLE_WHILE_NEW) which gives the current value.

My requirements in short - I have a ADF editable Table. Based on a flag whether it is SET or NOT, i need to make a particular column such that the inputTextBox on this column must appear for only the new rows inserted into the table. For all the existing rows users should not be allowed to edit values on this column.

I know this can be controlled with the UPDATABLE property on the attribute in the view object by setting the value as "WHILE  NEW".

Now i need to control this through code at runtime.

Please let me know on ow to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

change read-only property of your field according to your flag value